# Can't use port 8080

Tags: windows-10, port

When I'm trying to run a service (RavenDB) on port 8080 it stops and the Windows Logs show the following error:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Net.HttpListenerException: Failed to listen on prefix 'http://+:8080/' because it conflicts with an existing registration on the machine.
```

Acccording to IIS and `netstat -an | find "8080"` the port is currently not in use.

If I change the port to any other, the problem disappears.

Comment: if you type `telnet localhost 8080`, does anything respond?

Comment: I'm getting `Connecting To localhost...Could not open connection to the host, on port 8080: Connect failed`

Comment: so there is definitely nothing listening. I wonder where .net finds its 'existing registrations'

Answer (score 1):

Port 8080 may actually be in use. To replicate [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40876467/41410)

> netstat -a only lists connected sockets and listening socket.
>
> -a            Displays all connections and listening ports. Neither
>   connect nor listen was called on your socket, so it falls outside the
>   purview of netstat -a.
>
> However, since Windows 10, you can use netstat -q.
>
> -q            Displays all connections, listening ports, and bound

You could also try to view the port using tcpview from the [SysInternals suite](https://live.sysinternals.com/). Sort by port number. It will also tell you the process using the port, which you can then kill.

Comment: The port doesn't show up there either. I'll look at the SysInternals suite, though. Thanks